# Why doesn't this perl regex capture the last character?

Tags: regex, perl

let $PWD =  /Unix_Volume/Users/a/b/c/d

I would expect:

```
echo $PWD | perl -ne 'if( /(\w+)[^\/]/ ){ print $1; }'
```

to display "Unix_Volume".  However, it displays "Unix_Volum." Why doesn't the regex capture the last character?

Comment: I want to unask this question. `use Path::Class; (file '/Unix_Volume/Users/a/b/c/d')->parent->dir_list;` returns `('', qw(Unix_Volume Users a b c))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since \w doesen't have a forward slash in its class, why do you need [^\/] ?

/(\w+)/ will do. It captures the **first** occurance of this class.

**edit**: /.***\b**(\w+)/ to capture the last occurance.

Answer (score 8):

(\w+)  => Unix_Volum

[^\/]  => e (not a /)

/      => /

Comment: +1, beat me to it. `[^\/]` is forcing it to capture just one more character before it reaches a `/`.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
export PWD=/Unix_Volume/Users/a/b/c/d
perl -MFile::Spec -e'print((File::Spec->splitdir($ENV{_pwd}))[1],"\n")'
```

You should always use the modules that come with Perl where possible.  For a list of them, see `perldoc perlmodlib`.

Answer (score 0):

The `(\w+)`group matches and captures the word characters "Unix_Volume" greedily, leaving the position at the / after "Unix_Volume".

The `[^\/]` class forces the engine to back up (the greedy `+` quantifier gives up characters it's matched to satisfy atoms that follow it) to match a character that is not "/", matching the "e" at the end of "Unix_Volume". Since the matched "e" is outside the capturing group you're left with "Unix_Volum" in $1.